# Return specific element in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wanting the ability to create a method where I can check against any entity held in my table via one call. Right now, I only know how to return the first element in my table like so:

```
 EntityModel.Entity entity = (from e in context.Entities
                                     select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, I'm wanting to grab the third entity held in my context. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Tables are unordered sets; "the third element" makes no sense when any element could be at any position.  You must apply an explicit ordering before "the third element" is a meaningful operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I'm wanting to grab the third entity held in my context.

You can use `Skip` but before that you should `Order` your collection like:

```
var entity = context.Entities
                    .OrderBy(r=> r.SomeField)
                    .Skip(2)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

There is no concept of order in table's data, unless some order is explicitly specified. So if you use `Skip` without `OrderBy`, you will not be guaranteed to get same item every time with your query.